# What is the meaning of Andrew words "one does not know"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English fantasy movie, *Bicentennial Man*, Sir Richard teach some Joke to *Andrew* (Robot),

> Sir Richard: Knock-knock.
>
> Andrew: "Knock-knock"?
>
> Sir Richard: No, knock-knock, someone's at the door.
>
> Andrew: Shall one get it, sir?
>
> Sir Richard: No, no. No. Y-you say, "who's there," Andrew.
>
> Andrew: Who's there, Andrew?
>
> Sir Richard: No, just "who's there?"
>
> Andrew: **One does not know, sir**.

Andrew says he **don't know**. So here **know** means refers to what exactly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Andrew is answering the question **"who's there?"** of the last phrase Sir Richard  gave, and that by saying **One does not know, sir**, which means he doesn't know who's there.

Basically Andrew didn't know that Sir Richard was trying to tell a joke.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the **know**, you need to understand the context of the scene. As you mentioned, Sir Richard is trying to teach Andrew a joke. The problem Sir Richard is having is that Andrew is misinterpreting every part of Sir Richard's explanation of the classic "knock-knock" joke.

When Sir Richard says knock-knock, Andrew doesn't understand that Sir Richard is simulating a door knock. When Sir Richard says "someone's at the door", Andrew understands that to mean that someone is literally at the door, rather than at the door in the joke. When Sir Richard says "say who's there, Andrew", Andrew thinks he has to repeat the "who's there *Andrew*", not realising Sir Richard was only saying Andrew to refer to him.

The last sentence is Andrew once again taking what Sir Richard said literally. When Sir Richard says "No, just "who's there?"*, Andrew assumes Sir Richard is asking him who's there, and doesn't realise that Sir Richard is only correcting Andrew's mistake from the last line, and is still teaching him the joke. As Andrew doesn't know who's there, he says that he doesn't know.